# Python opts attribute in command line arguments

Tags: python

In the following code, I am trying to parse the arguments of the command line:

```
import sys, getopt
opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],'hs:c:i:I')
opts = dict(opts)

print opts
print args

if '-s-' in opts:
    print opts['-s']
```

When I run the code, I got:

```
{}
['python', 'Practice5.py', '-s', 'stop_list.txt', '-c', 'documents.txt', '-i', 'index.txt', '-I']
```

The command line is:

```
python Practice5.py -s stop_list.txt -c documents.txt -i index.txt -I
```

Why does the opts have null values?

Comment: When I ran the command I got the following output. {'-I': '', '-i': 'index.txt', '-c': 'documents.txt', '-s': 'stop_list.txt'}
[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I use Spyder, the problem was with the command arguments. The command must be:

```
-s stop_list.txt -c documents.txt -i index.txt -I
```

without `python Practice5.py`

In the regular command line, it works fine with `python Practice5.py`

Answer (score 1):

Testing this with *only* the actual arguments getting passed to `getopt`, I get the expected behaviour:

```
>>> import getopt
>>> opts, args = getopt.getopt(['-s', 'stop_list.txt', '-c', 'documents.txt', '-i', 'index.txt', '-I'], 'hs:c:i:I')
>>> opts
[('-s', 'stop_list.txt'), ('-c', 'documents.txt'), ('-i', 'index.txt'), ('-I', '')]
>>> args
[]
```

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getopt.html):

> *args* is the argument list to be parsed, without the leading reference to the running program.

If you also have `'python'` and your script name in `sys.argv`, you need to slice more from the start of it. You could also consider switching to `argparse`, as suggested in the `getopt` docs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html); it's far easier once you understand.